# Angular 5 Multiple Service Worker in one domain

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have two service workers  in two application on the same domain (both Angular 5):

- one inside /frontend/
- second inside /backend/

I am using @angular/service-worker package to manage service worker.

When i build prod version and deploy my applications something strange happens.

When im enter first to http://my.domain/frontend/ i can't go to http://my.domain/backend/ because service worker loading files and redirect me to http://my.domain/frontend/

What is wrong with this setup? i need to change file name of that service worker, or just i can't have two angular application on the same domain with this setup

Comment: There shouldn't be any technical reason for this not to work. Most likely a bug in the configuration or something. Could you please add your configuration and the generated SW code to your question? That would help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue (after restarting the browser, server down - just got data from the ServiceWorker as expected, but mixed up). Then I came across [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474908/using-multiple-javascript-service-workers-at-the-same-domain-but-different-folde) and changed the `names` of the `assetGroups` to distinct names between all (2 in my case for now) apps.

eg:

ngws-config.json from App 1:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "sw-app-app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html"],
        "versionedFiles": ["/*.bundle.css", "/*.bundle.js", "/*.chunk.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "sw-app-assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

ngws-config.json from App 2:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "sw-app-two-app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html"],
        "versionedFiles": ["/*.bundle.css", "/*.bundle.js", "/*.chunk.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "sw-app-two-assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

because of:

`The Cache Storage API (and other storage mechanisms, like IndexedDB) are shared throughout the entire origin, and by default there's no "sharding" or namespace segregation.`

My guess is that this default names are used in the `Cache Storage` for both apps (but there is also a hash, that is what still confuses me). I also checked the `Cache Storage` and deleted all ngsw:* entries not containig *sw-app* (or *sw-app-two*).

After these changes everything seemed to work better but then after some reloads (with active server) I realised that my *sw-app* entries from the `Cache Storage` where gone after opening `sw-app-two`. There were only *sw-app-two* entries and one entry named `ngsw:db:control` left. This entry only contained the `assetGroups` of the `sw-app-two's` `ngsw-conig.json` (under `manifest`). After opening *sw-app* again, the content in the `manifest` for the `assetGroups` changed to `sw-app` and the `sw-app-two` content was gone.

So I have `ngsw:db:control` left with *sw-app* content, and the other `Cache Storage` entry names contain *sw-app-two*. When I open both apps (server down) there is always `sw-app-two` coming up (without errors, but it is just an app without real content). This mixup works for one app, also confusing somehow.

Some more details, but still no solution. Would love to check the angular code and make a PR but .... at least file an issue. I am quite sure the `Cache Storage` gets mixed up between apps under the same origin.

**PS:** When you set the `baseHref` be sure to check this github issues too: [#8515](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8515) [#8516](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8516)

**EDIT:** I created [issue #21388](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21388)

**EDIT(2):**

`Service Worker scripts must be hosted at the same origin (Protocol + Domain name + Port).` mentioned at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871787/how-to-register-a-service-worker-from-different-sub-domain)

I will create a sub-domain for each app and run multiple http servers on different ports locally to test it. This should work and seems to be the only solution for use cases like this. Hope this is an option for you too! If not, you can write a comment to boost the *freq label* at the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21388) a bit ;-)

**EDIT(3):**

I found a solution that seems to work, but you have to edit the `ngsw-worker.js` after the build process. Simply replace `ngsw:db:` with a name that is unique for the app (eg: `ngsw:db:sw-app-one:` for `sw-app-one`, `ngsw:db:sw-app-two:` for `sw-app-two`)

**EDIT(4):**

Sadly the solution does **not work**, the entries for the `control` key (eg: `ngsw:db:sw-app-one:control`) will be overwritten with the content of another app ... I will comment at the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21388) for further details ...

Comment: Thanks soo much, for investigation in that case!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're onto something with your 3rd edit @skydever.

However if you look at the `deleteAllCahces` method of `ngsw-worker.js` you'll find that it will delete everything that starts with the `ngsw:` prefix. So instead of adding the unique app id after `ngsw:` rather replace `ngsw:` with `ngsw-appone:` (where `appone` is the unique app id for your app).

So your suggestion of editing the `ngsw-worker.js` after the build seems to work, and you have to replace `ngsw:` with `ngsw-your_unique_app_id:`