# Angular - Service worker for multiple sites with the same domain

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

In my project I have used a Service worker just for updating the cached files after any new deployment takes place. And there are multiple sites with the same domain that have been used.

**The issue I am facing is this:**
If I go through one site to another site then it is moving back to 1st site showing the page not found. For example, I have opened the URL 'domain.com/site1/profile/1' in one tab, and in another tab, I am opening 'domain.com/site2/profile/2' then It is redirecting to 'domain.com/site1/profile/2' and shows page-not-found. **---** I analyzed the problem and got to know there are two service workers are active for the site1 as well as the site2.

Is there any way I can unregister the previous service worker i.e. of site1 if the new service worker of site2 been found and vice versa?

I also have tried the solution provided by @tony, but didnt get any luck. Please refer attached image after applying the solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CkHH.png)

Comment: Is this URL 'domain.com/site1/profile/2' correct? I saw your first URL is 'domain.com/site1/profile/1'

Comment: Yes, when I open 'domain.com/site2/profile/2' in another tab while in one tab my 'domain.com/site1/profile/1' is open then it is redirecting to 'domain.com/site1/profile/2' which is site1's url.

Comment: might be possible solution for this, [link][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133070/6581776

Comment: @tony I have tried the solution, but still couldn't get any luck. I changed Appname and Assestname also according to the applications and also I am using different ngsw-config files for each applications.