# Is Ionic or Angular can have more than one web worker ? Multiple web worker in Ionic Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, web-worker

Is Ionic or Angular can have more than one web worker ? Multiple web worker in Ionic Angular app ?

Comment: Did you try? What error did you face?

Answer (score 0):

yes, Angular and Ionic can have more than one worker in the application, but you most be careful because if you don't set up the configuration of the workers well you could get mixed up information, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926704/angular-5-multiple-service-worker-in-one-domain) is a post of stack talking about that issue.

Comment: ServiceWorkers and Web Workers (a.k.a dedicated Workers) are different beasts.

Comment: yes, I guess that is the question off amir, I mean that you can have different workers in the app, let's see if he response

Comment: @Robertocd_98 yes you are correct. Need to implement mulitple webworker in ionic app