# Laravel Progressive Web APP Multiple App Installation from Same Website

Tags: laravel, progressive-web-apps

In laravel when we are going to install the app (by progressive web app) from our web site at first time banner will be shown for install app and it was installed and when we we want to install the another app from same web site no banner for app install shown(pwa banner) for another application and also the chrome add to home screen also not present (instead of add to home screen it will show option for open in last one install app) is there any solution that we can install multiple app from same web site

Answer (score 0):

The browser remembers that you added the PWA to your home screen (A2HS)
If you want to see that prompt again, you need to:
-- Clear your browser cache
-- If Chrome Desktop, uninstall the PWA from here: [chrome://apps/](http://chrome://apps/)
-- If Chrome Android, uninstall the WebApk listed in your apps
-- All others, remove the shortcut icon

---

If you are talking about multiple applications/Service workers hosted on the same domain, this may help
[Using multiple javascript service workers at the same domain but different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474908/using-multiple-javascript-service-workers-at-the-same-domain-but-different-folde)

Comment: how we can create multiple progressive web app from same website for each page.  I want to know about how the chrome is going to know whether progressive web app for the website already install or not

Comment: See the link above
Looks like you can use different folders with the same domain
Most people probably just have one PWA @ each domain
So you may have to build your own prototype to see what happens
also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486756/can-i-have-multiple-pwas-on-the-same-domain-under-different-url-paths?rq=1  also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280821/multiple-pwas-in-the-same-domain